# Show Hide after clicking svg path

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, onclick

So I've pretty much figured this out in a way that works.

Currently I'm using

`<set attributeName="visibility" from="hidden" to="visible" begin="Mali.click" end="Mali.mouseout"></set>`

Which works I guess, but is there a way to end the svg animation with another click? Because when I set end = mali.click it just makes it so nothing happens at all. I need like a nextclick or something.

Comment: make a demo on fiddle

Comment: id values must be unique, your file is not valid. You need to switch (probably to classes) because the road you're going down is a dead end.